# ASP.NET a problem with jQuery's ajax function

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have button and that jQuery script (to start the progress bar):

```
<script src="../_Files/JScripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../_Files/JScripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 var intervalID;
 $("#<%=this.Button1.ClientID%>").click(
            function() {

                intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 500);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "CustomerImport.aspx/ExecuteImport",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function()
                    {
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 100);
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                        $("#result").text('ok');
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        );

   function updateProgress() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CustomerImport.aspx/GetProgress",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#result").text = msg.d;
                    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
                    if (value < 100) {
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", msg.d);
                        $("#result").text(msg.d);
                    }
                    else {
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                        window.location = window.location;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

the method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void ExecuteImport()
    {
        _Presenter.ExecuteImport();
    }
```

the problem is, that method is NOT being invoked. Why ?

When I replace the `$.ajax` for the e.g `alert('ok');` the alert shows, so it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you decorate your service class with the [`[ScriptService]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute? Also try changing the data parameter to: `data: { }`. What does [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) says about this? Is there a request being sent? If yes what does the server respond?

Also you have a mistake in your url (web services have the ASMX extension). You wrote:

```
CustomerImport.aspx/ExecuteImport
```

While it should be:

```
CustomerImport.asmx/ExecuteImport
```

Here's a complete working example that you may adapt to your needs:

Web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class CustomerImport : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void ExecuteImport()
    {
    }
}
```

Calling web page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/CustomerImport.asmx/ExecuteImport',
                data: { },
                success: function () {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form runat="server">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FireBug says: Unknown web method GetProgress.Parameter name: methodName

Comment: I see that ExecuteImport and GetProgress method are unknown, firebug says

Comment: hm, but it is not a WebService, it is a aspx Page, is it makes a difference ?

Comment: Oh, ASPX page? Yes it makes a difference of course. Take a look at this link for an example: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ Your method **has to be static** in the ASPX page.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov who is responsible for `CustomerImport.asmx/ExecuteImport` to go to the page.asmx and execute the Excute function ? which module ? can you provide a link ?

Answer (score 1):

Add in the error function to the ajax call...  Hopefully you'll get some info back, as to why the call failed.

Are you using firebug?  Watch the net tab.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: jsonEncodedParams,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {

    }, //success
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus == "timeout") {
        alert('The request timed out, please resubmit');
      } //if
      else {
        alert(errorThrown);
      } //else
    } //error
  }); //ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your server-side endpoint is a "page method", [it must be declared as static](http://encosia.com/2008/04/16/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ExecuteImport()
{
    _Presenter.ExecuteImport();
}
```

Comment: who is responsible for CustomerImport.asmx/ExecuteImport to go to the page.asmx and execute the Excute function ? which module ? can you provide a link ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The specific ASP.NET HttpModule?

Comment: When yu request a URI in the internet , by its URL , it goes to a page , no to a method. So who is reponsible to Extract the page from the URL , and go to the Method which was also supplied in the URL. you are talking about a related info in your (excellent) site. I ask this question since I saw in you site the Jquery Ajax example with the static Asp.net function.